# How can I assign values with mypy and @property?

Tags: python, properties, mypy

I'm using the @property decorator and I assign a value to that property. However, mypy throws an error with my code (which works). Do I do something wrong? How can I fix my code so that mypy doesn't complain?

### MVCE

```py
# Core Library
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class ListNode(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, value):
        """Every list node should have a value at initialization."""

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self):
        """Read the value attribute"""

    @abstractmethod
    def next(self):
        """Read the next attribute"""


class SinglyLinkedListNode(ListNode):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None  # Optional[SinglyLinkedListNode]

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next

    @next.setter
    def next(self, next_):
        self._next = next_


def reverse(list_node: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    """Reverse a list."""
    current = list_node
    previous = None

    while current is not None:
        previous, current.next, current = current, previous, current.next  # This throws the error

    return previous
```

Error:

```
mpu/datastructures/lists.py:47: error: Cannot assign to a method
mpu/datastructures/lists.py:47: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ListNode", variable has type "Callable[[], Any]")
mpu/datastructures/lists.py:47: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[], Any]", variable has type "ListNode")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example there is probably a typo, instead of

```py
self.next = None
```

it should be

```py
self._next = None
```

Because we are overwriting `property` with field your code seems to work, but not probably how it was intended.

Also it seems that `ListNode.next` should be a `property` too like

```py
class ListNode(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    ...

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def next(self):
        """Read the next attribute"""
```

Finally adding setter for `ListNode.next`

```py
    @next.setter
    def next(self, next_):
        """Write the next attribute"""
```

makes errors to disappear.

---

BTW decorating `ListNode.next` setter with `abstractmethod` causes errors

```sh
> mypy test.py
test.py:14: error: Overloaded method has both abstract and non-abstract variants
test.py:19: error: Decorated property not supported
test.py:53: error: Property "next" defined in "ListNode" is read-only
```

and seems to be redundant, because removing setter for `SinglyLinkedListNode.next` causes

```sh
> mypy test.py
test.py:37: error: Read-only property cannot override read-write property
```

Also for [type comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments) to work we need to add `type:` prefix

```py
class SinglyLinkedListNode(ListNode):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self._next = None  # type: Optional[SinglyLinkedListNode]
```

(we can also add `from typing import Optional`, because PyCharm isn't satisfied saying "*Unresolved reference 'Optional'*", but it seems to be ok for mypy).